# How to change the value of User isActive:boolean in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

User Model which has isActive:Boolean

When button is clicked is redirect to route and find user with id from params.

after finding user it checks value of isActive.

If the value is not true then change it to false or if value is true chnage it to true

```
<form action="/admin/user/<%= user._id %>/status?_method=PUT" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-group-sm"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></button>
</form>
```

Button which sends req as PUT to route

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    mobile: String,
    gender: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Route for find and change the value of isActive

```
router.put("/admin/user/:id/status", (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundUser) => {
        console.log(foundUser.isActive);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (foundUser.isActive == false) {
            User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: {isActive: true}});
            res.redirect("/admin/users-details");
        } else {
            User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: {isActive: false}});
            res.redirect("/admin/users-details");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you know it not work?

Comment: @hoangdv I checked in database, isActive value doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

in your model `isActive` field type is `Boolean`, but you check it like a string:

`else if (foundUser.isActive !== "true")`

change it `else if(foundUser.isActive)`

also you can perform both finding and updaing user in one mongodb query like below:
`User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, user) {
    user.isActive = !user.isActive;
    user.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
        ...
    });
});`

Comment: I try this but it still not working                                                                                                                     else if (!foundUser.isActive) { 
User.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: {isActive: false}});
res.redirect("/admin/users-details");

Comment: @jimit_jd sorry, change the condition: `else if (foundUser.isActive)` ... if the user is active then make it inactive and vice versa.

Comment: @jimit_jd can you see output of `console.log(foundUser.isActive)` ?

Comment: yes i can see output of console.log(foundUser.isActive) but when try to change its not work

Answer (score 0):

Try wait until updating process throw a result before redirect page, with the example you can see what happen when you try to update a record:

```
router.put("/admin/user/:id/status", (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundUser) => {
        console.log(foundUser.isActive);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect("/admin/users-details?error=" + err.toString());
        }
        User.update({ _id: foundUser._id }, { $set: { isActive: !foundUser.isActive } }, (err2, result) => {
            console.log(err, result);
            res.redirect("/admin/users-details");
        });
    });
});
```